# Getting barcode4j working with Docmosis Tornado

Tags: barcode4j, docmosis

My requirement is to have a Word.doc file with barcoding embedded, and then turn that into a PDF. I'm trying docmosis for this project, and its worked so far - except when I try to generate the pdf with barcoding enabled. I'm getting the following error, which I'm guessing is a missing dependency, which I'm hoping someone can identify for me.

This is how I'm launching the Docmosis service:

```
java -jar  docmosisTornado2.3.war -classpath ..\barcode4j-2.1.0\build\barcode4j.jar
```

and this is the error I'm getting back:

```
Exception in thread "ODFExplodedTemplatePopulator10987705" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/krysalis/barcode4j/impl/AbstractBarco
deBean
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at com.docmosis.template.analysis.barcode.BarcodeGeneratorFactory$_A.A(line:64)
        at com.docmosis.template.analysis.barcode.BarcodeGeneratorFactory$_A.access$0(line:59)
        at com.docmosis.template.analysis.barcode.BarcodeGeneratorFactory.getGenerator(line:39)
        at com.docmosis.template.population.openoffice.PopulationContext.getImage(line:495)
        at com.docmosis.template.population.openoffice.ContentStreamPopulatorObfImpl.A(line:2590)
        at com.docmosis.template.population.openoffice.ContentStreamPopulatorObfImpl.access$1(line:2581)
        at com.docmosis.template.population.openoffice.ContentStreamPopulatorObfImpl$2.A(line:1569)
        at com.docmosis.template.population.openoffice.ContentStreamPopulatorObfImpl.A(line:1539)
        at com.docmosis.template.population.openoffice.ContentStreamPopulatorObfImpl.A(line:2781)
        at com.docmosis.template.population.openoffice.ContentStreamPopulatorObfImpl.A(line:1124)
        at com.docmosis.template.population.openoffice.ContentStreamPopulatorObfImpl.A(line:481)
        at com.docmosis.template.population.openoffice.ContentStreamPopulatorObfImpl.A(line:942)
        at com.docmosis.template.population.openoffice.ContentStreamPopulatorObfImpl.A(line:481)
        at com.docmosis.template.population.openoffice.ContentStreamPopulatorObfImpl.A(line:1127)
        at com.docmosis.template.population.openoffice.ContentStreamPopulatorObfImpl.A(line:481)
        at com.docmosis.template.population.openoffice.ContentStreamPopulatorObfImpl.A(line:1127)
        at com.docmosis.template.population.openoffice.ContentStreamPopulatorObfImpl.A(line:481)
        at com.docmosis.template.population.openoffice.ContentStreamPopulatorObfImpl.A(line:516)
        at com.docmosis.template.population.openoffice.ContentStreamPopulatorObfImpl.A(line:481)
        at com.docmosis.template.population.openoffice.ContentStreamPopulatorObfImpl.A(line:384)
        at com.docmosis.template.population.openoffice.ODFExplodedTemplatePopulator.processContent(line:203)
        at com.docmosis.template.population.openoffice.ODFExplodedTemplatePopulator.processTask(line:113)
        at com.docmosis.util.pipeline.impl.AbstractDataWorker.run(line:129)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.krysalis.barcode4j.impl.AbstractBarcodeBean
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1854)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1703)
        ... 26 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error shows that the **barcode4j** classes are not available.  For Docmosis-java, add the barcode4j.jar to your classpath.  If you are using Docmosis Tornado you'll need to await the next release.

Docmosis supports barcodes **code39**, **code128** and **itf14** based on barcode4j.  It's available in the [Docmosis Cloud](https://www.docmosis.com/resources/cloud.html) (REST API over the internet) by default and [Docmosis-Java](https://www.docmosis.com/resources/docmosis-java.html) (Java API) if you add barcode4j.jar to your class path.  [Docmosis Tornado](https://www.docmosis.com/resources/tornado.html) (REST API to local web server) is expected to include it from release 2.4.